# Laptop won't run Windows and won't boot Ubuntu

Tags: boot, laptop, bios

I'm trying to fix a laptop, but for unknown reasons, a fresh installation of Windows (10) won't get past the login screen, and a fresh installation of Ubuntu (16.04) isn't detected as bootable.

I'm hoping a BIOS update might fix something, but the updates are executable files, and I can't figure out how to run those in the current situation.
I do have a Windows installation USB and a Ubuntu Live USB, both of which the device can boot to.

I just need an OS to run on this thing, whether Windows or Linux. Any ideas on how to get something working?

Device: Acer Aspire R5-571T
OS: Brick
Boot type: UEFI (Legacy does not work any better)
BIOS version 1.03, latest is 1.09

Comment: There should be BIOS upgrades on the manufacturer's website.

Comment: I can't install them. They're executable files. I must have shortened my post too much to make sense, I should get some sleep now and rephrase in the morning when I can think normally.

Comment: Ok, I edited the post. Hopefully it's more coherent, but I should probably double-check that in the morning.

Comment: 'Windows screwed itself over'... I read that as it can succesfully run windows. No updates needed. but **something** else is messed up. And you might need to fix that rather than run firmware updates. (At least as far as windows in concerned. WIndows might very well work around a broken EFI firmware where a sane OS might try to stick to specs).

Comment: It might also help if you add more details than 'now the laptop won't boot Ubuntu'. Why not? Does give an error? If so, which error? Does it not even start the installation medium? If so what are you using to install from and how is your system configured (regular EFI boot? Something weird EFI32 boot? Compatability Shims (aka CSP aka BIOS compatible boot). Etc etc.

Comment: Ok, I cleaned up the mess of a post I left last night. Sorry about that.  The installation USB works, but the installed OS itself does not. I am using UEFI (secure boot off). And Windows did some... inexplicable things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to me that your main question for now, is that you need to update the BIOS, but is unable to install an OS to run the update.

You may try to [download](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-create-usb-bootable-drive) and boot into Windows PE (WinPE), and try to run the BIOS update utility from that.  According to Microsoft's description, [Windows PE (WinPE) for Windows 10](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-intro) is a small operating system used to install, deploy, and repair Windows 10.

It appeared that [the method worked for some Dell computers](https://garytown.com/dell-bios-upgrade-in-osd-winpe-x64).  I have not tried that out from a Dell computer nor an Acer computer but theoretically it should work.

Comment: Now MakeWinPEMedia doesn't want to work. Hooray. Insists it can't format my USB, even though it is formatting it.